# Seeking Underground Infrastructure Data for Brisbane (Australia)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, government, australia

I am in Brisbane, Australia and am looking for GIS data relating to underground services (such as buried water mains, power lines, gas lines, etc).

Where might I find some of this information?

Comment: any data from any location?

Answer (score 2):

[OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/-27.61411/153.08344&layers=N) has underground items in its data so you can pull data from there.